# Getting a results of DB query basing on rows number by function

Tags: php, database, class, loops

**This will be long.**
I'm making class which will get data about teams - 5 Steam users basing on 32bit SteamIDs stored in database - 1 row = 1 team.
I want to get one result, when I specify teamid and all rows, when it's not defined(or when equals 'all'). And here starts the problem, 'cause specified team gives return, but I can't get all rows, it just gives null when `var_dump`ed.
I have already created this method:

```
public static function baseData($teamid = null){
        if(!empty($teamid)){
            if(is_numeric($teamid)){
                DB::getInstance()->get('', 'o90eprrzc3v8', ['53qwi8md3rm7', '=', $teamid]);
            }
            elseif($teamid == 'all'){
                DB::getInstance()->getOrdered('', 'o90eprrzc3v8', '53qwi8md3rm7', 'ASC');
            }
            return DB::getInstance()->results();
        }
        return false;
    }
```

where DB class' methods I use in Team class looks like this:

```
public function bquery($sql, $params = array()){
        $this->_error = false;

        if($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql)){
            $x = 1;
            if(count($params)) {
                foreach($params as $param){
                    $this->_query->bindValue($x, $param);
                    $x++;
                }
            }

            if($this->_query->execute()){
                $this->_results = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
                $this->_count = $this->_query->rowCount();
            } 
            else{
                $this->_error = true;
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function action($action, $table, $where = null){
        if(!empty($where)){
            (array)$where;
            if(count($where) === 3){
                $operators = ['=', '>', '<', '>=', '<='];

                $field = $where[0];
                $operator = $where[1];
                $value = $where[2];

                if(in_array($operator, $operators)){
                    $sql = "{$action} FROM {$table} WHERE {$field} {$operator} ?";

                    if(!$this->bquery($sql, array($value))->error()){
                        return $this;
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
        elseif(empty($where)){
            $sql = "{$action} FROM {$table}";

            if(!$this->bquery($sql, null)->error()){
                        return $this;
            }
        }
    }
public function get($selector, $table, $where = null){
        if(empty($selector)){
            if(!empty($where)){
                return $this->action('SELECT *', $table, $where);
            }
            else{
                return $this->action('SELECT *', $table);
            }
        }
        else{
            if(!empty($where)){
                return $this->action('SELECT '.$selector.'', $table, $where);
            }
            else{
                return $this->action('SELECT '.$selector.'', $table);
            }
        }
    }

    public function getOrdered($selector, $table, $order, $orderType, $where = null){
        $orderType = strtoupper($orderType);
        if(($selector = '') or (empty($selector))){
            return $this->action('SELECT *', $table, 'ORDER BY '.$order.' '.$orderType.'');
        }
        else{
            return $this->action('SELECT '.$selector.'', $table, 'ORDER BY '.$order.' '.$orderType.'');
        }
    }

    public function results(){
        return $this->_results;
    }
public function count(){
        return $this->_count;
    }
```

And from this I want to
 - loop through results
 - return all variables, so I can echo them on index page
I've tried to create method for this, but until `baseData()` doesn't work, I can't check if it's working (it probably won't, as most of apps I write :D):

```
public static function getSteamData($teamid = 0){
        for($teamid = 0;$teamid<(DB::getInstance()->count());$teamid++){
            $result = self::baseData($teamid);

            $stmid_capt = "STEAM_0:$result->stmidcapt_1:$result->stmidcapt_2";
            $stmid_p2 = "STEAM_0:$result->stmidp2_1:$result->stmidp2_2";
            $stmid_p3 = "STEAM_0:$result->stmidp3_1:$result->stmidp3_2";
            $stmid_p4 = "STEAM_0:$result->stmidp4_1:$result->stmidp4_2";
            $stmid_p5 = "STEAM_0:$result->stmidp5_1:$result->stmidp5_2";

            $stmid64 = [
                'capt' => convertId($result->stmidcapt_2),
                'p2' => convertId($result->stmidp2_2),
                'p3' => convertId($result->stmidp3_2),
                'p4' => convertId($result->stmidp4_2),
                'p5' => convertId($result->stmidp5_2),
            ];

            $stmid3 = [
                'capt' => convertId3($result->stmidcapt_1, $result->stmidcapt_2),
                'p2' => convertId3($result->stmidp2_1, $result->stmidp2_2),
                'p3' => convertId3($result->stmidp3_1, $result->stmidp3_2),
                'p4' => convertId3($result->stmidp4_1, $result->stmidp4_2),
                'p5' => convertId3($result->stmidp5_1, $result->stmidp5_2),
            ];

            $profile_get[0] = Arrays::get('response→players', json_decode(file_get_contents('http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key='.Arrays::get("steamapi→key").'&steamids='.$stmid64['capt']),true));
            $profile_get[1] = Arrays::get('response→players', json_decode(file_get_contents('http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key='.Arrays::get("steamapi→key").'&steamids='.$stmid64['p2']),true));
            $profile_get[2] = Arrays::get('response→players', json_decode(file_get_contents('http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key='.Arrays::get("steamapi→key").'&steamids='.$stmid64['p3']),true));
            $profile_get[3] = Arrays::get('response→players', json_decode(file_get_contents('http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key='.Arrays::get("steamapi→key").'&steamids='.$stmid64['p4']),true));
            $profile_get[4] = Arrays::get('response→players', json_decode(file_get_contents('http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key='.Arrays::get("steamapi→key").'&steamids='.$stmid64['p5']),true));

            $profile_avatar = [
                'capt' => Arrays::get('0→avatarmedium', $profile_get[0]),
                'p2' => Arrays::get('0→avatarmedium', $profile_get[1]),
                'p3' => Arrays::get('0→avatarmedium', $profile_get[2]),
                'p4' => Arrays::get('0→avatarmedium', $profile_get[3]),
                'p5' => Arrays::get('0→avatarmedium', $profile_get[4]),
            ];

            $profile_status = [
                'capt' => Arrays::get('0→personastate', $profile_get[0]),
                'p2' => Arrays::get('0→personastate', $profile_get[1]),
                'p3' => Arrays::get('0→personastate', $profile_get[2]),
                'p4' => Arrays::get('0→personastate', $profile_get[3]),
                'p5' => Arrays::get('0→personastate', $profile_get[4]),
            ];

            $profile_name = [
                'capt' => escape(Arrays::get('0→personaname', $profile_get[0])),
                'p2' => escape(Arrays::get('0→personaname', $profile_get[1])),
                'p3' => escape(Arrays::get('0→personaname', $profile_get[2])),
                'p4' => escape(Arrays::get('0→personaname', $profile_get[3])),
                'p5' => escape(Arrays::get('0→personaname', $profile_get[4]))
            ];
        }
    }
```

I hope someone was so patient to read all of this stuff and can help me with making it work :D

Comment: the if in `baseData` is dangerous... if it doesn't match the if, neither the elseif, it will crash, and it is certainly what it's doing here... maybe the parameter is not numeric and not equal to "all"... can't it be null ? log its value to check it out...

Comment: I set it fixed for time of checking the code, so I don't think it can have other value.

Comment: If you are sure it goes into your `else`, then it should be a problem with your `getOrdered(...)` call... what is this method doing ? are you sure about the parameters ?

Comment: OK, I found, that there was no way to use getOrdered because of action method, which had $where param, and getOrdered had no. So getOrdered works fine now :)